# Passing jquery datepicker value to php variable using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery ui datepicker and the picked date is passing to a php page using `post` method. The full code of my php file is given below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Datepicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: (new Date(2013, 1 - 1, 26)),
            changeMonth: true,
            <!-- numberOfMonths: 1, -->
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#endDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
        $( "#endDate" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            changeMonth: true,
            <!-- numberOfMonths: 1, -->
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#startDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="date.php" method="post">
<label for="startDate">startDate</label>
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" />
<label for="endDate">endDate</label>
<input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php 
$startdate = isset($_POST['startDate']) ? $_POST['startDate'] : '';
echo $startdate;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, the value of the picked date is passed to php only after submitting the form using submit button. How can I pass the value on select of the date picker using ajax? So that, the php `echo` function will display date dynamically on selecting the datepicker.

Comment: So do you want this variable passed to PHP or for it to be displayed on your page dynamically? I am a bit confused as what you are looking for

Comment: This calls for AJAX basics, have a look at the syntax and documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) The main attributes you would need to lookout for is, the `url`, `type`, `data`, and `done` callback function.

Comment: `will display date dynamically on selecting the datepicker`? What are you trying to achieve? Is it some kind of date format? then probably you can do it using javascript

Comment: @Chitowns24 - I want to display the selected values dynamically using php variable. ie, without pressing `Submit` button, the value of the php variable should change and display when the user picks a date.